# How to set log level for a specific class in spring with logback.xml?

Tags: spring, logging, logback

I am trying to not log debug message in class `com.data.march.ClientUtils`. For that, I think that I can change the log level of that class in the logback.xml to `error`.

Here is my logback.xml:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="dailyRollingFileAppender"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>c:/Logs/logato.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <FileNamePattern>c:/Logato/Data/Logs/Logato.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{35} - %msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="minuteRollingFileAppender"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover every minute -->
            <FileNamePattern>c:/Data/Logs/minutes/Logato-minute.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}.log
            </FileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 minutes' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%-4relative %-5level [%thread] %logger{35} - %msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>.%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.data" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.data.march.ClientUtils" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

But my attempt failed. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try with adding this:

```
<logger name="com.data.march.ClientUtils" level="error"/>
```

Comment: Does this support wild cards like "com.data.**.*Test".  I'm not able to get this to work.

Comment: @John you can use name="com.data", it means "all loggers package com.data"

Comment: I thought Spring Boot had some common way to do this by adding 
logging.level.com.data.march.ClientUtils=ERROR.  I've seen this work before, but not always. It would be nice if they, made, *ONE* logger and have *ONE* way to configure it.